# HTML Purifier preserve spaces

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

Is there anyway to make HTML Purifier preserve the implict spaces that would typically be seen in rendered HTML?

For example you would typically expect a space between `Foo` and `Bar` in these following cases:

```
Foo<br/>Bar
```

[Example 1](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php?filter%5BAutoFormat.AutoParagraph%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.Linkify%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveSpansWithoutAttributes%5D=0&filter%5BNull_CSS.AllowedProperties%5D=1&filter%5BCore.CollectErrors%5D=0&filter%5BHTML.Allowed%5D=p&filter%5BNull_HTML.Doctype%5D=1&filter%5BHTML.SafeObject%5D=0&filter%5BHTML.TidyLevel%5D=medium&filter%5BURI.DisableExternalResources%5D=0&filter%5BNull_URI.Munge%5D=1&html=Foo%3Cbr%2F%3EBar&submit=Submit)

```
<div>Foo</div><div>Bar</div>
```

[Example 2](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php?filter%5BAutoFormat.AutoParagraph%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.Linkify%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveSpansWithoutAttributes%5D=0&filter%5BNull_CSS.AllowedProperties%5D=1&filter%5BCore.CollectErrors%5D=0&filter%5BHTML.Allowed%5D=p&filter%5BNull_HTML.Doctype%5D=1&filter%5BHTML.SafeObject%5D=0&filter%5BHTML.TidyLevel%5D=medium&filter%5BURI.DisableExternalResources%5D=0&filter%5BNull_URI.Munge%5D=1&html=%3Cdiv%3EFoo%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3Cdiv%3EBar%3C%2Fdiv%3E&submit=Submit)

Answer (score 1):

I have a cruel plan - replace any tag closing ">" to space and remove double spaces

```
<?php
$text = '<div>test</div><div>me</div>';

$text = preg_replace('/(<\/[a-z]+>)/', '$1 ', $text);
$text = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', strip_tags($text)));

var_dump($text);
```

Returns

```
string(7) "test me"
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like HTMLPurifier is not removing whitespace, it's removing the tags all together because it doesn't recognize them (which is weird).

In regards to `Foo<br/>Bar`

- `Error Line 1, Column 3: Unrecognized <br /> tag removed`

In regards to `<div>Foo</div><div>Bar</div>`

- `Error Line 1, Column 0: Unrecognized <div> tag removed`
- `Error Line 1, Column 8: Unrecognized </div> tag removed`
- `Error Line 1, Column 14: Unrecognized <div> tag removed`
- `Error Line 1, Column 22: Unrecognized </div> tag removed`

You can see this by enabling CollectErrors on the Live Demo.

[image]

Maybe try allowing `div`, and `br`: http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#HTML.AllowedElements

[image]

Here are the results from the [Live Demo](http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php?filter%5BAutoFormat.AutoParagraph%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.DisplayLinkURI%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.Linkify%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveEmpty%5D=0&filter%5BAutoFormat.RemoveSpansWithoutAttributes%5D=0&filter%5BNull_CSS.AllowedProperties%5D=1&filter%5BCore.CollectErrors%5D=1&filter%5BHTML.Allowed%5D=p%0D%0Adiv%0D%0Abr&filter%5BNull_HTML.Doctype%5D=1&filter%5BHTML.SafeObject%5D=0&filter%5BHTML.TidyLevel%5D=none&filter%5BURI.DisableExternalResources%5D=0&filter%5BNull_URI.Munge%5D=1&html=Foo%3Cbr%2F%3EBar&submit=Submit&experimental=1):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Im talking about the implicit white space, i.e. from the rendered HTML output there will be a new line. I purposely disallowed those tags.

Comment: Yes, bascally all I allow is `strong, em, strike, b, i` etc

Comment: I see, so you're only allowing styling HTML. If there is an HTML tag, and it's stripped, there was no implicit whitespace or new line to begin with. You would need to replace them with something before sending them through HTMLpurifier.

Comment: The thing is I only allow styling HTML in one place that it is rendered (basically a content preview), but I do allow block level tags when its rendered in other places (the detail view).